# How to write multiple for loop print results into a single line in a text file in python and beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, text-files, python-itertools

The snippet below is working though not very presentable. I cant figure out how to write what is on display into outputfile.txt file. I want the snippet to write what is on display into a text file.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from itertools import groupby

url = "https://bscscan.com/tokentxns"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

data = []
for tr in soup.select("tr:has(td)"):
    tds = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in tr.select("td")]
    _, txn_hash, tm, age, from_, _, to_, value, token = tds
    a = tr.select("a")[-1]["href"][7:]
    data.append((a, value, token))

data = sorted(data)
for _, g in groupby(data, lambda k: k[2]):
    g = list(map(list, g))
    trans = [f"{len(g)} TRANS", *[""] * (len(g) - 1)]
    total = sum(float(s.replace(",", "")) for _, s, *_ in g)
    total = [f"{total} TOTAL", *[""] * (len(g) - 1)]
    
    for subl in g[0:]:
        subl[1] = ""
        subl = ' '.join(map(str, subl))
    print(subl, end="\r")
    

    for tr, t, subl in zip(trans, total, g):
        print ("\t\t" + str(tr) + "   "  + str(t))
```

Current Output: Saved in the outputfile.txt - not presentable

```
['0x088bebef4e371757509e64d3508b6da6f376e2ac', '', 'DrakeBall To...(DBall)']    
['0x0e09fabb73bd3ade0a17ecc321fd13a19e81ce82', '', 'PancakeSwap ...(Cake)']    
['0x154a9f9cbd3449ad22fdae23044319d6ef2a1fab', '', 'CryptoBlades...(SKILL)']    
['0x3621f5b9786dfa52759c0392a72ac6818ed2c84f', '', 'EQIFI (EQX)']  1 TRANS  182513805147.0 TOTAL
['0x363621cb1b32590c55f283432d91530d77cf532f', '', 'BABYCAKE_Div...(BABYCA...)']  1 TRANS  37840.385 TOTAL
['0x4fd6d315bef387fad2322fbc64368fc443f0886d', '', 'Pancake LPs (Cake-L...)']
```

Wanted Output Written to outputfile.txt:

```
0x9c65ab58d8d978db963e63f2bfb7121627e3a739  MDX Token (MDX)         1 TRANS   97.10128249433292 TOTAL
0xacb8f52dc63bb752a51186d1c55868adbffee9c1  BunnyPark (BP)          3 TRANS   340.2936687126161 TOTAL
0xb7dba4c673bedb174dc3ff7ec65d17c863d39b16  FAT CAKE (FATCAK...)    2 TRANS   6408272.9511043355 TOTAL
0xbb4cdb9cbd36b01bd1cbaebf2de08d9173bc095c  Wrapped BNB (WBNB)      2 TRANS   0.4472397706686812 TOTAL
0xdae18b46e0dbfecd441c47de1a6d7b57455a83ee  Pancake LPs (Cake-L...) 1 TRANS   0.22360679774997796 TOTAL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A somewhat simpler possible approach:

```
tab = soup.select_one('table')
data = []
for entry in tab.select('table tbody tr'):
    cells = entry.select('td')
    token = cells[-1].select_one('a')['href'].split('token/')[1]
    data.append([cells[-1].text,cells[-2].text,token])

for k, g in groupby(sorted(data), lambda k: k[0]):
    g = list(map(list, g))
    tot = sum([float(i[1].replace(',','')) for i in g ])    
    print(k,',',g[0][2],',',len(g),"TRANS",',',tot,'TOTAL')
```

At the time I ran it, the output was something like:

```
 BABY DOGE BI... (BABYDB) , 0x6d9fb3332f62fc044d5075feeea597a92f1ce0ad , 1 TRANS , 60634807618.46239 TOTAL
 BLADE KNIGHT (BK) , 0x2bfe217caa076027ac24af0e261ed311478ddf78 , 1 TRANS , 4.800279067385619 TOTAL
 Binance-Peg ... (BSC-US...) , 0x55d398326f99059ff775485246999027b3197955 , 1 TRANS , 15.242784023721224 TOTAL
```

etc.

Comment: This is very great and helpful. It works and very simple. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since the first value in your output is a list you can just `join` the values to make it a single string. If you want these two values in separate variables then you can just `split` them again and store it as you wish. Now since you are just writing into a `txt` you can just save the last print statement in a variable and write it into the file directly.

I have made 2 changes to your code above:

1. used `join` command
2. changed where `subl` was printed and aligned that print statement by multiplying spaces.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from itertools import groupby

url = "https://bscscan.com/tokentxns"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

data = []
for tr in soup.select("tr:has(td)"):
    tds = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in tr.select("td")]
    _, txn_hash, tm, age, from_, _, to_, value, token = tds
    a = tr.select("a")[-1]["href"][7:]
    data.append((a, value, token))

data = sorted(data)

for _, g in groupby(data, lambda k: k[2]):
    g = list(map(list, g))
    trans = [f"{len(g)} TRANS", *[""] * (len(g) - 1)]
    total = sum(float(s.replace(",", "")) for _, s, *_ in g)
    total = [f"{total} TOTAL", *[""] * (len(g) - 1)]
    
    for subl in g[0:]:
        subl[1] = ""
        subl = ' '.join(map(str, subl))

    g = [' '.join(i) for i in g]        # join to change the 2D list to 1D
    i =0
    for tr, t, subl in zip(trans, total, g):
        if i ==0:    # removes duplicates in the for loop
            # multiplying the space value based on the max len of the values of lsit g
            print (subl + ' '* (70-len(subl)) +  "\t " + str(tr) + "\t "  + str(t))
            i+=1
    print()

# 70 is max length a value inside list g had so I am subtracting it with current values len
# to make the spaces next column start at the same point
```

This was the output I got:

[image]

Comment: Nice explaining and very helpful idea. Thank you